# Full change/improvement list for Beyond Earth Rising Tide compared to the original game?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide

What are the full patch notes / changes of the Beyond Earth Rising Tide expansion compared to the original game?

I have only seen the marketing-like features advertised, but not a more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't seen a full "patch note" style change log, but the Civilization Wiki has a list of the major changes [here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Rising_Tide), with links to the new units/techs etc.

Here's an excerpt of the major changes:

### New diplomacy system

> Diplomacy has been rebuilt "from scratch" in Rising Tide. Players can trade for traits that can improve how a civilization functions. A new 20xDiplomaticCapitalBE Diplomatic Capital system has been added to facilitate diplomacy.

### Expanded aquatic gameplay

> In addition to a slew of new naval units such as the submarine, Rising Tide players can build floating cities that can move around the map. Previously land based resources such as Firaxite can be found in the water. Explorers can also now find resource pods and conduct expeditions in the ocean. And the chances of you spawning next to an alien nest is at 15%.

### Expanded exploration options

> Explorers have much more to do in Rising Tide. Players can now find artifacts that give large bonuses to players. Combining artifacts can lead to buildings and wonders that would not have been available any other way.

### Hybrid affinities

> Earning different affinity points in Rising Tide has a synergistic effect. Units can now be built that require multiple affinity points. Standard units can also be upgraded to new hybrid forms.